# Generate SAS macro code without executing it

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Is there a way I can print the SAS code generated by a macro without executing it?

Thanks

Comment: short answer you probably don't want to hear: use `%put` statements

Comment: @user2877959 your suggestion will do the trick for small macros, but not for complex and long ones. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Are you talking about a stored compiled macro?  Or do you have access to the source, but you still want to have it printed? Or are you generating the code yourself?

Comment: I am talking about a macro I wrote, I do of course have access to the source. Mine is simple enough that I can generate the SAS code by substituting macro variables with their values. But I am interested in the general case, and I am quite convinced now that there is no general solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not in general. A macro is a program that generates SAS code, so the only way to know what code it's going to generate is to run it. In some very simple cases, you might be able to parse the macro and determine what SAS code will be generated, but for any more complex case, you'd have to re-implement a program to read, parse and execute a macro for this to work. See also [the Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Comment: So what I understood is that; if such facility exists, it surely wouldn't work for all macros.

Comment: Correct. Just consider what processing a macro might do - it might connect to a live production database and then generate some code for every order received in the last 30 minutes, with some additional code for orders over a certain value... how would any general macro analyzer be able to predict how many orders the macro would process for a given run?

Comment: I think this answer misinterprets what is wanted to some extent.  Yes, you would probably have to run the _macro_, but running the macro without running the SAS code it generates seems like it fits the goal of the question.  I don't disagree that for some cases the goal is impossible, but it seems likely that the question is less compex than that.

Comment: That's true, Joe, of course; one could probably do some static analysis on the macro code and determine whether it is simple enough for that to work, and my answer admitted that possibility... however, in general, macros may take different execution paths depending on the results of SAS code they have already generated, so I wouldn't want anyone to embark on this project without being aware of the insurmountable limitations ahead.

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to get to what you want, that work at least some of the time.

You can set `options obs=0;` and then run the macro (With `MPRINT` turned on).  That will run the macro but won't process any rows of data.  This will work for many macros; but it will overwrite datasets, so it's not safe if you care about whatever it's writing out over being preserved.

```
%macro do_something;
  data test;
    set sashelp.class;
  run;
%mend do_something;

options mprint;
options obs=0;

%do_something;
```

`WORK.TEST` was overwritten, note, but no observations were processed.

Now, if you're talking about a stored compiled macro (this seems the most useful scenario, no?), then it depends on how it was stored.  If it was stored with the `/source` switch, then you can get the source back with `%COPY`.

```
libname sasdir "e:\temp"; 
options mstored sasmstore=sasdir; 

%macro do_something/store source;
  data test;
    set sashelp.class;
  run;
%mend do_something;

%copy do_something/source;
```

It requires it to have been compiled with the `source` flag, though.  If it wasn't, then the source is unrecoverable short of running the code.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another approach, if your macro is mainly data step and proc sql, is to use the `run cancel;` and `proc sql noexec;` options, eg as follows:

```
%macro example(somelogic=1,execute=NO);

  %local cancel noexec;
  %if &execute=NO %then %do;
    %let cancel=cancel;
    %let noexec=noexec;
  %end;

  data some_ds;
    set some_other_ds;
  %if &somelogic %then %do;
    this=that;
  %end;
  run &cancel;

  proc sql &noexec;
  create table maybe as 
    select * from have;

%mend;
```

In this way your code will be generated / syntax checked but not executed.

Of course - this is a 'handle with care' approach as there are still many things that can still be changed within a macro context. @Chris Long is correct - there is no reliable way of generating the SAS code without executing it (as the actual code generated is often dependent on the result of earlier executions).

Answer (score 0):

You could try using PROC STREAM. 
Let's define a simple macro

```
%macro mymacro;
 proc print data=sashelp.class; run;
%mend;
```

Make a fileref to contain the resulting code

```
filename mycode temp;
```

Now you can use `PROC STREAM` to convert the macro call into text.

```
proc stream outfile=mycode; BEGIN
%mymacro
;;;;
```

It should work for any macro that does not need to make decisions based on the results of the code that it is generating.